# How to check if object already exists in HashSet?

Tags: java, set

This [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CheckifaparticularelementexistsinHashSet.htm) makes it look easy:

```
HashSet<Integer> hSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

hSet.add(new Integer("1"));
hSet.add(new Integer("2"));
hSet.add(new Integer("3"));

System.out.println(hSet.contains(new Integer("3")));
```

> true

But when I use it on a Movie object (which I want to check):

```
Set<Movie> hSet = new HashSet<Movie>();

hSet.add(new Movie(222, "Lord of the Rings", "something"));
System.out.println(hSet);

System.out.println(hSet.contains(new Movie(222, "Lord of the Rings", "something")));
```

> false

The hSet print shows:

> [id: 222name: Lord of the Rings]

I don't see a difference in adding a new Integer or adding a new movie object to the list. So why isn't my example working?

//edit.

If anyone is looking for a good reference, [this helped me out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722485/hashset-storing-equal-objects).

Comment: Does `Movie` implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly?

Comment: The reason for this difference is that `Integer` overrides `hashCode` and `equals`, while `Movie` does not.

Comment: Because to work correctly within a Hashing thingy, your class Movie must implement hashCode(). And implementing equals() is also a good thing there. And Integer does override these two methods, your class most likely does not.

Comment: Oh yea, that's something I forgot. Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `hashcode` and `equals` method in Movie class.

In hashset whenever we add the objects, before adding the object it will check the `hashcode` value of an object by **overridding the hashcode**
If the calculated hashcode value is already available in the set, then it will **call equals method** and check the object which we are going to add is equal with the already available object in set.
If the **object is equal then it will not add** it into the set or else it will add the object into the set.